Restricting servlet-mapping url-pattern
We are deploying a Jersey application and the servlet class configured extends ServletContainer.
When we use the mapping:
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>appcore</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/myapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

Everything works perfectly, but if I try to restrict the URL pattern one level or more, for instance:
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>appcore</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/myapi/secondlevel/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

I get a 404 exception, and seems that the URL cannot be redirected. Any hint what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!
